# Transform complex json event using dbt

Tags: json, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, extract, dbt

I’m currently working on a dbt transformation for JSON data stored in a Snowflake table, and I’m facing some challenges. The JSON structure involves nested arrays, and I need to extract specific information to create a structured table. Here’s a simplified example of the JSON structure:

```
    {
    "eventid": 123,
    "consumerID": 123,
    "metadata": {
        "sessionid": "555",
        "timestamp": "2024-02-22T09:18:05.848",
        "vtnr": {
            "vtnr_dat": "606",
        },
    },
    "data": [{
            "vehicledata": {
                "vehicleid": 125,
                "vehicletype": "B",
            },
            "tariff": [{
                    "tariffid": 1,
                    "pricekh": 12.43,
                    "pricetk": null,
                    "year": 2002,
                    "kh": true,
                    "tk": null,
                }, {
                    "tarrifid": 1,
                    "pricekh": null,
                    "pricetk": 20.28,
                    "year": 2002,
                    "kh": null,
                    "tk": null,
                }
            ]
        }, {
            "vehicledata": {
                "vehicleid": 126,
                "vehicletype": "B",
            },
            "tariff": [{
                    "tariffid": 5,
                    "pricekh": 10.00,
                    "pricetk": null,
                    "year": 2022,
                    "kh": true,
                    "tk": null,
                    "vk": null
                }, {
                    "tariffid": 5,
                    "pricekh": null,
                    "pricetk": 59.28,
                    "pricevk": null,
                    "kh": null,
                    "tk": true,
                    "vk": null
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

At the end I should get the following table and results:

```
vehicletype tariffid    year    kh      tk      vk      pricekh pricetk pricevk
555         2024-02-22T09:18:05.848 606         125         B           1           2002    true    true    null    12.43   20.28   null
555         2024-02-22T09:18:05.848 606         126         B           5           2022    true    true    null    10.00   59.00   null
```

I tried to exctract metadata and information about vehicles with lateral flatten but I couldn’t find the solution how to combine that with more objects for tariff in a single row of data.

Any idea how to solve this transformation?

Comment: This is more of a Snowflake issue than an dbt issue. I'm pretty sure Snowflake has decently robust json parsing tools/functions. I'd consider just trying to create the table with a single target column and building from there instead of trying to do it all in one step